# How to Count Data in SQLAlchemy in String Data Column [Python]?

Tags: python, database, string, count, sqlalchemy

Now i'm working to calculate sum of population using SQL Alchemy. I want to sum the population column but i have problem that the data consists of dot delimiter.

How do i replace dot separator in SQL Alchemy? Here's my code:

```html
stmt = select([demography.columns.nama, demography.columns.populasi])
stmt = stmt.order_by(demography.columns.pulau)
results = connection.execute(stmt).fetchall()
print(*results, sep='\n')
```

`('Ibukota Jakarta', '9.607.787')
('Jawa Barat', '43.053.732')
('Jawa Tengah', '32.382.657')
('Daerah Istimewa Yogyakarta', '3.457.491')
('Jawa Timur', '37.476.757')
('Banten', '10.632.166')`

Answer (score 0):

What would I do is instead of doing it in the sqlalchemy query, I will get first the result then do parsing and calculation like below:

```
stmt = select([demography.columns.nama, demography.columns.populasi])
stmt = stmt.order_by(demography.columns.pulau)
results = connection.execute(stmt).fetchall()

for res in results:
    population = res[1] #this is the index for population count
    population_list.append(int(''.join(population.split('.'))))
print(sum(population_list)) #prints 136610590
```